# REGEX Expression - NetSuite Saved Search

Tags: regex, netsuite

I am having an issue pulling out the text that is following the `"label":"[TEXT]"` after each occurrence in the below example.

Basically, I am looking to see how I can get Equip and Parts Pick/Pack, Sales Order Picking, Transfer Order Picking, etc

REGEX_REPLACE, or REGEX_SUBSTR - Oracle NetSuite Saved Search.

I am attempting to use this but the problem is REGEX_SUBSTR doesn't support lookbacks

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR({custrecord_rfs_menu_menu}, ':(?<="label":")(.*?)(?=",)/gm')
```

```
NAME - {custrecord_rfs_menu_menu}
{"label":"Equip and Parts Pick/Pack","type":"Menu","nodes":[{"label":"Sales Order Picking","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"28","versionId":"1553","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"Transfer Order Picking","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"38","versionId":"1554","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"Bin Transfer","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"8","versionId":"1555","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"Inventory Transfer","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"16","versionId":"1556","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"RMA Receiving","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"26","versionId":"1557","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"Purchase Order Receiving","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"24","versionId":"1860","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"Bin Putaway","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"5","versionId":"2064","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"Bin Transfer (Serial)","type":"MenuItem","menuItemId":"11","versionId":"2184","taskNotificationSearchId":"0"},{"label":"
```

Comment: could you also provide: **the string, the regexp you tried, the result** you got. that way may be someone would be able to help more

Comment: I would second @d.k's advice, and also include the result you **expect**.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am attempting to use this but the problem is REGEX_SUBSTR doesn't support lookbacks ..."*

Try a *capture pattern*.

```
"label":"(.*?)"
```